# $_SESSION does not gets set on remote server

Tags: php, session

I am writing a log in page in php, and I am having trouble setting up $_SESSION. I am new to php and I don't know what I am doing wrong. The Script works fine on localhost, but when I push it to the remote server, it does not work. Could it be the php.ini file? Thanks for your help.

```
         <?
         start_session();

            $dbc = mysqli_connect($host,$name,$dpassword,$database) or die('Error can not connect to corp database');
                $q="SELECT * FROM corporate WHERE (email='$theemail' AND password='$md5pass' AND activated = '1')";

                $result= mysqli_query($dbc,$q) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));;

                if(@mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
                {
                    //get the entire row
                    $getrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    //also tired 
                    //$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    //set session, but does not get set!
                    $_SESSION['lname'] = $getrow['lname'];
                    $_SESSION['fname'] = $getrow['fname'];


                        //set cookie for an hour
                        setcookie("lname", $getrow['lname'], time()+60*60,"/","http://www.limozoor.com",1);
                        setcookie("fname",$getrow['fname'],time()+60*60,"/","http://www.limozoor.com",1);

                        //if no header is not sent, send it.
                        if(!headers_sent())
                        {
                            header('Location: http://www.limozoor.com/login/homepage.php'); 
                            exit();
                        }//inner

                }//outter
         }
        ?>
```

php.ini

```
          [Session]
          session.save_handler = files

          session.save_path = /tmp

          session.use_cookies = 1

          session.name = sid

          session.auto_start = 0

          session.cookie_lifetime = 0

          session.cookie_path = /

          session.cookie_domain =

          session.serialize_handler = php

          session.gc_divisor     = 100

          session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

          session.bug_compat_42 = 1
          session.bug_compat_warn = 1

          session.referer_check =

          session.entropy_length = 0

          session.entropy_file =

          session.cache_limiter = nocache

          session.cache_expire = 180

          session.use_trans_sid = 1
```

Comment: Are the cookies set? And does the redirect happen as expected?

Comment: cookies are set, and I get redirected back to index.php which means there was no data stored in Session.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing these  code segments

```
 start_session();
```

into

```
session_start();
```

and

```
$_SESSION['lname'] = $getrow['lname'];
$_SESSION['fname'] = $getrow['fname'];
```

into

```
if($getrow['lname']!='' && $getrow['fname']!=''){
   $_SESSION['lname'] = $getrow['lname'];
   $_SESSION['fname'] = $getrow['fname'];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be just an oversight but the function in your code is incorrect: it is should not be `start_session()` but `session_start()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Besides that, I don't see anything in your php.ini settings that may cause session not to work.
You should put those lines in your php.ini `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` and `display_errors = On`. It will allow you to see as many error messages as possible.

Finally you can check apache error log to see if you can find any meaningful error messages. By default on Linux it will be in /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: Another possible cause (but highly improbable) would be the apache user not having permissions to write to /tmp

Comment: Sorry, I did use session_start(), I just wrote it, without pasting it from the script. That is not the problem!.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using:

```
session_start();
```

not

```
start_session();
```

if that function is not properly called your browser will not actually store any session data.

[Reference for session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your session start?

you have start_session(), but i think it should be session_start()